# Maximum number of pairings of elements in a sequence

Tags: algorithm

I'm given n numbers `a_1,a_2,...,a_n` and they are given two me in and non-decreasing sequence, meaning `a_1<=a_2<=...<=a_n` in an array and I can pair two of them, say `a_i` and `a_j` if and only if `2a_i <= a_j`. How many disjoint pairings can I maximally make?

I'm at a total loss here. I tried to do it greedily. Say I pair the largest one with the smallest one, erase them from sequence and proceed recursively. But that's wrong, because for `1,2,3,8` I would get one pair `(1,8)`, but I can make two pairs `(1,2)` and `(3,8)`. Based on that counterexample I tried to solve it differently. Say I pair `a_i` with the first number that I can. Then there's this counterexample `1,3,4,6`. I would again get one pair `(1,3)`, but in reality I can make two pairs `(1,4)` and `(3,6)`.

Can anybody give me a hint about how to proceed?

I think that the following n-element table would be useful. For elements `a_1,...,a_n` `tab[j]` would denote the number of elements, for which `2a_i` is smaller than `a_j`. This table can simply be computed in `O(n)` time. But I don't know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that the best case is where you can split the array in the middle and match the first half with the second half, so the maximum possible answer is *n / 2*.

```
1 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 8

1 -> 5
2 -> 6
3 -> 7
4 -> 8
```

We can show that if there exists a solution with *k* assignments, it can be done by pairing *a<sub>i</sub>* with *a<sub>n - k + i</sub>* for all *1 ≤ i ≤ k*:

```
1 2 5 | 6 7 | 8 9 10

1 -> 8
2 -> 9
5 -> 10
```

We can also show that if there exists a solution with *k ≥ 1* assignments, there also exists a solution with *k - 1* assignments. Thus we can binary search for the maximum *k* and use the greedy assignment to check whether it is in fact possible to have a certain amount of assignments in every step.

Runtime: *O(n log n)*

**UPDATE** (due to user [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay)): From what we assume above, we can instead also greedily assign the element from the first half in increasing order to the first unassigned element in the second half. We can do so by maintaining a pointer to the element in the second half that comes after the one we assigned last. Runtime: *O(n)*

Comment: Thank you :) Quite simple nad very effective :)

Comment: @ArekKrawczyk: If I can remember correctly, this was a Codeforces A problem in some Div1 contest 2 months from now or so. There is a linear time solution as well, but it's slightly more complicated

Comment: Based on your assumptions, you will always match elements from the first half to elements from the second. So you can simply match each element from the first half to the first possible element from the second half that hasn't been matched yet - this will give an O(n) solution.

Comment: @interjay: Yes, I think that works too. Mind if I edit this alternative solution into my answer?